# How do I install Ubuntu using squid-deb-proxy-client?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, squid-deb-proxy

I saw some answers using a preseed file (that were said not to work because of a bug), but I'm interested in using the standard live image and not editing the preseed file there. If squid-deb-proxy is on another machine on the network, can I just install the client in the live system and install as normal, or is there something more to it?